Changing child img element's source by hovering parent
I have a React component that is basically a card with a title, and an image. Id'like the image to change on hover of the card, not of the img element, which is what I have happening now.
I know I can do this with CSS and the background property, but I'd rather the button stay re-useable as a component and keep accepting props rather than tying the :hover effect to some static CSS.
Here is what I have at the moment:
export default function ExternalProfile({
  title,
  imageUrl,
  altImageUrl,
  href,
}) {
  // Make sure elements exist before getting their ID
  React.useEffect(() => {
    let imageVar = document.getElementById("id" + title) as HTMLImageElement;
    if (imageVar) {
      console.log(imageVar);
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <a
      href={href}
      className="card externalCard"
      onMouseOver={(imageVar.src=altImageUrl)}
      onMouseOut={(imageVar.src=imageUrl)}
    >
      <h3>{title}</h3>
      <img
        id={"id" + title}
        className="externalImage"
        src={imageUrl}
        alt={title + " icon"}
      />
      <img className="arrow" src="/arrow.svg" alt="Arrow" />
    </a>
  );
}

But this gives the error Cannot find name 'imageVar'
I know this isn't a file naming problem, as these are most of the solutions I seem to find online, and my files are already all named with the .tsx extension.

write a seperate functions to handle the onMouseOver and onMouseOut
 const handleMouseOver = (event) => {
          event.target.src = altImageUrl; 
    };
        
 const handleMouseOut = (event) => {
          event.target.src = imageUrl; 
    };

and call this in onMouseOver and onMouseOut event in anchor tag.

This worked, thank you! Although I had to modify it slightly because this.target just returns the element that the action takes place on. This is what I ended up with: const handleMouseOver = (event) => {     event.target.querySelector(".externalImage").src = altImageUrl;   };   const handleMouseOut = (event) => {     event.target.querySelector(".externalImage").src = imageUrl;   };

good to hear, way to go.

<a
      href={href}
      className="card externalCard"
      onMouseOver={(imageVar.src = `${altImageUrl}`)}
      onMouseOut={(imageVar.src = `${imageUrl}`)}
    >

But this gives the error Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'MouseEventHandler'.
instead of giving the image variables inside interpolation
 onMouseOver={(imageVar.src=`${altImageUrl}`)}

try giving like this
onMouseOver={(imageVar.src=altImageUrl)}

do the same for other one too.

Thank you, and that solves the string error, but the problem now is that I can't access the src property of the returned Element List. I will update my question with more details!
